# What is it called when in a two-phrase sentence the second is unrelated to the first?

Tags: grammar, sentence

When we talk, each sentence that follows is related logically to the previous sentence, for example, we say:

> "I get up in the morning (sentence 1) and brush my teeth (sentence 2)"

Sentence 2 makes sense to follow after sentence 1.

What if we say something like this:

> "I get up in the morning (sentence 1) and dogs can't fly (sentence 2)"

Here sentence 2 makes no sense and is unrelated to sentence 1.
Another example:

> "It's cold today but my house is clean".

Is there a name for such phrases?

Answer (score 1):

The normal description of this is to say that the second clause (not 'phrase') is a ***Non Sequitur***. That's from a Latin sentence that means 'It does not follow', and it can be used to refer to **any** situation in which something is said that makes no sense in the same context as the previous discourse.

*Non Sequitur* also refers to any statement in a logical or philosophical argument that's not supported by previous evidence or arguments; that's where the term originated, in philosophy and logic. A non sequitur is the opposite of something that 'follows (from X)'.

Comment: I would say that the third example is not, necessarily, a non sequitur  as it might make sense in the right context. For instance "Yesterday was warm and dry so I could wash all my floors and leave the windows open to dry them. _Today is cold but my house is clean_."